# Why is the ensurepip module not working for my homebrew python 3.9 installation?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I've installed python 3.9 via homebrew on my macOS Big Sur system.  In order to get pip3 working, I tried to use the ensurepip module:

```
python3 -m ensurepip
```

Which then succeeds (apparently):

```
Successfully installed pip-21.2.4 setuptools-57.4.0
```

But, when I try to run pip3, it cannot find the pip module:

```
$ python3 -m pip
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named pip
```

I can see that the pip module has indeed been installed in this directory:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip
```

But, when I run python3 I see this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

So, why did `python3 -m ensurepip` decide to install the pip module into a directory that it doesn't actually look for modules?  And more importantly, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The homebrew installation for python3 failed to complete properly because of the infamous `/usr/local` permissions issue with the macOS.  So, the postinstall step didn't get triggered for python3, which sets up pip3, etc.  Because of this, the ensurepip module installed pip to a directory that was not in the python3's module search path.

So, I fixed the ownership issues in `/usr/local` for homebrew, (though I'm not sure why this still doesn't work properly out of the box).

Then, when I went back to run the postinstall, it failed without telling me anything.  So, I used the `--debug` option, and saw that it was angry because the site-packages directory wasn't empty (due to my previous installation of pip using ensurepip).  So, I wiped that directory with `rm -rf`, and re-ran the post-install.  Then, it worked.